# Subclassing with multiple constructors and **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, keyword-argument, subclassing

I am trying to build a parent class with multiple constructors (using the `@classmethod` constructor). In general I don't have an issue with this but this time I need the `__init__` method to take arbitrary keyword arguments coming from each different constructor so I cannot specify them in advance. This class is then subclassed multiple times throughout the code using the various constructors.
The issue is that I can't seem to initiate the parent class in the subclasses. I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'var1'
```

This is a simplified example that replicates my error:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    @classmethod
    def from_args(cls, var1):
        return cls(var1=var1)


class SubTest(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubTest, self).from_args('pie')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = SubTest()
    print(obj.var1)
```

Comment: Why does ``SubTest.__init__`` attempt to call ``super().from_args``? It should at the very least call either ``super().__init__`` or ``self.from_args``. Also, since ``from_args`` *constructs a new* instance, and ``__init__`` *initialise an existing* instance, the calling the former from the latter seems not sensible.

Comment: Well, in that case, is there any way I can initialize the super using the from_args constructor (or something similar)? And this is a very simplified example. Obviously I don't just assign var1 in the real thing! And there are multiple constructors in the real class, not just one. But you are right, It slipped my mind that the from_args() constructs a new instance, it doesn't initialize the existing instance.

Comment: I'm not sure you've got the right tools in front of you if you want `SubTest()` to have the effect of the classmethod... You could perhaps rewrite the `__init__` to simply call `super().__init__(var1='pie')` or override the classmethod accordingly and use `SubTest.from_args()`.

Comment: Yes, it seems I went looking for a complicated solution when the correct answer is the one given by @MisterMiyagi: A simple init and then simple, normal class methods that set the desired attributes (or kwarg in my case) depending on the case. If you make your comment into an answer, I will accept it.